# p-Laplace Equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I’m trying to solve what I’ll call the p-Laplace Equation which is

$$\Delta_p u = 0$$

where $\Delta_p u$ is the p-Laplacian. It is defined as

$$\Delta_p u = \nabla \cdot (|\nabla|^{p-2} \nabla u).$$

Any ideas? I haven’t seen this in a book or anything. I just thought that by analogy,  there should be a solution to this equation too. Are there any properties of p-Harmonic functions like there are for Harmonic functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation
$$ \operatorname{div}(|Du|^{p-2} Du)=0 $$
is solved by a smooth minimizer of the functional
$$ I[w]:=\int_U |Dw|^p\,dx. $$

($D$:=gradient, $U$ some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Source: Partial Differential Equations, Second Ed., L. C. Evans (p. 514).

Comment: Could you tell me what chapter in the book this is mentioned in?

Comment: @user9143057 Added the page number. It is in Chapter 8.

Answer (score 1):

A PDE theoretic approach to this problem will ask whether $p$-harmonic functions exist on an appropriate domain subject to boundary constraints. This has been studied in detail, so I'll provide a brief summary of the results.

It's worth noting that this approach is probably different from what you're expecting, as existence theorems of this form do not give explicit solutions. I'm not sure if there's much work relating to finding explicit examples and proving various properties, but it's not very common in modern PDE theory. This is because this equation is much harder to study compared to the Laplace equation being nonlinear, so basic questions are difficult to establish, let alone finding explicit solutions and detailed properties.

A typical setup will involve solving the problem,

\begin{align} \Delta_p u = 0 &\text{ in } \Omega, \\
u = g &\text{ on } \partial\Omega, \end{align}

where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is some open bounded set and $g$ is some prescribed function.

As mentioned in Ryan's answer, this is the associated Euler-Lagrange equation of a functional. Hence standard variational methods (assuming $g$ and $\partial\Omega$ are sufficiently nice) gives a *weak solution* $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega).$ This for all $v \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ satisfies,

$$ \int_{\Omega} |Du|^{p-2}Du.Dv\, \mathrm{d}x = 0. $$

Note however that $u$ a-priori is not a classical solution, as it may not be continuous nor differentiable. Under suitable assumptions, some fairly hard analysis can show the weak solution $u$ lies in $C^{1,\alpha}(\Omega)$ for some $\alpha.$ In particular, it is continuously differentiable.

However this is the best we can say in general. An explicit counterexample for a non-$C^2$ $p$-harmonic function is given by,

$$ u(x) = \left(1 - |x|^{\frac p{p-1}}\right). $$

Note that if $p>2$ and $n \geq 2,$ this function is not twice differentiable at $0.$